# Comparing two multi column dataframes for statistical significance

Tags: python, statistics, analytics, p-value, significance

I have 2 dataframes.
Each dataframe contains 64 columns with each column containing 256 values. 
I need to compare these 2 dataframes for statistical significance.

I know only basics of statistics. 
What I Have done is calculate p-value for all columns for each dataframe.
Then I compare p-value of each column of 1 st dataframe to the p value of each column to the 2nd dataframe. 
EX: p value of 1 st column of 1st dataframe to p value of 1st column of 2nd dataframe.

Then I tell which columns are significantly different among 2 dataframes.

Is there any better way to do this.
I use python.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, the way you do it is not the way its meant to be. Let my highlight some points that you should always keep in mind when conducting such analyses:

**1.) Hypothesis first**

I strongly suggest to avoid testing everything against everything. This kind of exploratory data analysis will likely produce some significant results but it is also likely that you end up in a [multiple comparisons problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem). 
In simple terms: You have so many tests that the chance of seeing something significant which in fact is not is greatly increased (see also [Type I and Type II errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors)).

**2.) The p-value isn't all the magic**

Saying that you calculated the p-value for all columns doesn't tell which test you used. The p-value is just a "tool" from mathematical statistics that is used by a lot of tests (e.g. correlation, t-test, ANOVA, regression etc.). Having a significant p-value indicates that the difference/relationship you observed is statistically relevant (i.e. a systematic and not a random effect).

**3.) Consider sample and effect size**

Depending on which test you are using, the p-value is sensitive to the sample size you have. The greater your sample size, the more likely it is to find a significant effect. For instance, if you compare two groups with 1 million observations each, the smallest differences (which might also be random artifacts) can be significant. It is therefore important to also take a look at the effect size that tells you how large the observed really is (e.g. *r* for correlations, Cohen's *d* for t-tests, partial eta for ANOVAs etc.).

**SUMMARY**

So, if you want to get some real help here, I suggest to post some code and specify more concretely what (1) your research question is, (2) which tests you used, and (3) how your code and your output looks like.